# AngularJS - Clear all $watch on $destroy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a few `$watch` on my `scope`. I know that I a `$watch` will return its deregister function, and I can just call it to deregister it, but is there a way to just deregister all watchers on a scope in one simple command?

I want to basically deregister all of my watchers on `$destroy`, and I don't want to save ALL of these watchers, and call them all one by one.

There is a `$$watcher` attribute on the `scope`. Can I somehow use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically when `$destroy` is broadcasted from the scope, it also means that the scope has invoked the `$destroy()` method. This means that everything related to that scope is also being cleaned up, including the `watchers`, **[this part of the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L841)** shows how the `$destroy()` method empties the watchers of that scope.

Comment: oh, so I don't need to manually call the `watchers` on `$destory` to remove them?

Comment: KK makes more sense! Thanks

Comment: I had another question. If I set a `watcher` on the `$rootScope` inside a directive, and then the directive is destroyed, I do need to manually stop watching that correct? Since the `watch` is on the `$rootScope`, and not the `$scope`?

Comment: Yes, but don't call `$destroy()` on the `$rootScope`. You can de-register a watcher by invoking the function returned by `$rootScope.$watch()`.

Comment: No, I won't. What I meant is that in my directive scope, I will `scope.$on('$destroy')` and call the deregister function returned by the `$rootScope.$watch`